# What is the correct statement of Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, condensed-matter

There are various quite different statements in textbooks and other science literature as to Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission. So, what is the correct statement of Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission?

Comment: You appear to have asked this question with some prior ideas regarding the answer to this question, as has become clear from your comment to the only answer you've received so far. You should incorporate those thoughts into your question: Otherwise, you cannot expect to get an answer that addresses your confusion.

Comment: @Danu - My question is very simple, and not ambiguous. There is no confusion on my part, contrary to your allegation. Note my remarks related to my question. Your comment has contributed nothing to the answer.

Comment: I certainly do not intend to enter a controversy (i.e. I won't respond further in this thread), but it bears mention that what makes this question unclear is the word "correct". Correct by whose standards? By what is in the literature? By what Kirchhoff himself would say if we asked him? By what the broader community understands the statement to mean? By what you think is correct? Your questions are dripping preconceptions and as such they are unlikely to find answers you're satisfied with. (Why are you asking? To find out, or to cause controversy? This site is not a venue for the latter.)

Comment: @Emilio Pisanty - that you will not respond further, after only 1 comment, I can only wonder why you made a comment in the first place. You have contributed nothing to the answer of the very simple question. Your comment contains no rationale. It's pretty clear from your comment that you don't know Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission.

Comment: Please don't add rude remarks to encourage more answers; you'll catch more flies with honey than vinegar, as it were. Emilio & Danu offered good advice on how you can improve your question, you should take it.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - surely you jest. My question is simple. There has been much more irrelevant comment and hostility direct at me than attempts at answering. Why don't you try an answer instead of an irrelevant derisive comment?

Comment: I'm not terribly interested in the subject to pursue an answer, especially when you disregard any answer as wrong or misleading & that the answerer should reread the question (or other such nonsense)--seems to me that *you* are the one giving hostile remarks, not everyone else. Valid or not, your position on Kirchoff's law seems to be a minority position in academia, so it should be obvious that not everyone is going to agree with it. If you want credibility, you have to earn it (i.e., don't publish in [alternative science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progress_in_Physics) journals).

Comment: @Kyle Kanos - If you are by your own admission not interested in problems concerning thermal emission then I suggest you refrain from making irrelevant comments on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

The ratio of emissive power to the absorbitity is constant when the substance is at thermal equilibrium with surrounding. 
Or
The emissive power of a substance is equal to its absorbtivity under the same conditions.

Comment: - Thanks for your answer, but it is incorrect. You stated Stewart's Law. Your statement is a typical example of what incorrectly appears in textbooks and other science literature on Kirchhoff's Law, as pointed out in my notes to my question.

Comment: No my friend this is what I have learned and it is the correct statement as it appears in every text book which I have read eg. Cengle, Pk Nag and many more.

Comment: Precisely my point. Your statement of Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission is incorrect.  That emission = absorption at thermal equilibrium is Stewart's Law of Equivalence, not Kirchhoff's Law. The best source for Kirchhoff's Law is Kirchhoff.

Comment: The above statement is what i follow for Kirchoff law of thermal radiation and have never encountered with Stewart law so I am with what i have learned

Comment: Thanks for your admission that you have never heard of Stewart's Law. Stewart's Law and Kirchhoff's Law are not the same, contrary to the textbooks which so often confound the two and assign Stewart's Law to Kirchhoff. I have asked for the correct statement of Kirchhoff's Law. Does anybody on this website actually know the correct statement of Kirchhoff's Law, and if so, what is it?

Comment: I googled Stewart law for radiation but on contrary it shows Kirchoff law, this is interesting.

Comment: As I said in my notes to my question, "There are various quite different statements in textbooks and other science literature as to Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission." That a Google search does not turn up the right answer is not unexpected. So, what is the correct statement of Kirchhoff's Law of Thermal Emission?